# How to send push notification after every new image

Tags: android, android-studio, webserver

I have a web server where images are uploaded. I want to make an app so that the web server can send push notification when every new image is uploaded and when clicked the app redirects to the web server. 
Is this possible? I am new to android app development so any help is appreciated.
P.S. my app will do other stuff too

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending him a notification , you can show an alert box, saying "your image has been uploaded , and click the below link to check it out on server", and below you can provide your server's link.

P.S. sending notification for every image upload is not a good idea neither a good practise.